# 99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

I am a beginner to Python. I have a school project on making a program that can produce the song "99 Bottles of Beer on the Wall"

I would like to ask how do I make it show an error statement when I input a non integer value (a string, for example).

And also how can I avoid this error：

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skyfi\Desktop\Intro to Com. Prog. Notes\Chapter 11\zheng_tianyu_assignment4_part1.py", line 42, in <module>
    solution.song()
  File "C:\Users\skyfi\Desktop\Intro to Com. Prog. Notes\Chapter 11\zheng_tianyu_assignment4_part1.py", line 9, in song
    while int(i) > 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'no more'
```

Thank you for any help！

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = input("Input number of beer: ")

    def song(self):
        i = int(self.num)
        if i == 0:
            print("No more beers on the wall.")
        while int(i) > 0:
            for i in range(i, 0, -1):
                bottle = "bottles"

                if i == 1:
                    bottle = "bottle"

                if i >= 0:
                    print("{0} {1} of beer on the wall, {0} {1} of beer.".format(i, bottle))

                    i = i - 1

                if i == 1:
                    bottle = "bottle"

                if i == 0:
                    i = str(i)
                    i = "no more"
                    bottle = "bottles"

                print("Take one down, pass it around, {0} {1} of beer on the wall.".format(i, bottle))
                print(" ")




        if i < 0:
            print("Invalid input!")


solution = Assignment4Part1()

solution.song()
```

Comment: Please fix your code -- some has gotten lost in your paste.  The class declaration, for example.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need this:

```
    while int(i) > 0:
          ^^^
```

Your `i` is already an int.

If you want to catch errors for failed integer coversions, you need to wrap your conversion in a `try`/`except` block:

```
try:
   i = int(self.num)
except ValueError:
   # Your error handling code goes here
   # Note: i will have no value assigned.
```